# Veridis Biometric SDK: Get ANSI378 template from fingerprint image file

Tags: c#, .net, biometrics

I have been fiddling with the Veridis sdk 5.0. I need to get the ANSI 378 template from a fingerprint image file. Here is a sample code for that.

```
        var r = VeridisLicense.InstallLicense(myKey, string.Empty);
        var bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath) as Bitmap;
        var sample = new BiometricSample(bitmap, 500);
        var bioTemplate = new BiometricTemplate(sample, BiometricTemplateFormat.Ansi);
        var data = bioTemplate.GetData();
```

However, the app crashes with ntdll heap corruption error after executing the InstallLicense line. If I omit that, I get Veridis.Biometric.BiometricException "Not started (Error #-4)" from BiometricTemplate constructor. 
Can someone tell me what is going on here? I have the same problem while installing license with the dot net sample that comes with it. However, the demo application inside veridis sdk package does not give any error while installing the license.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot to call the static function `BiometricCapture.StartSDK(eventListener)`

You also will need a class that inherit from `ICaptureListener`. That new class will be your Event listener.